# ejabberd changing ports?

Tags: security, port, ejabberd

I changed the ports in the listen section (just added a 1 in front of them) in the /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg, but after a

```
/etc/init.d/ejabberd restart
```

The server still listens on the original ports. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Also the server doesn't seem to start up when the firewawall-rules are set. How Is that possible given that the firewall rules affect only eth0, not localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: Can you confirm that ejabberd was actually restarted?  You can do a `ps auxw |grep ejabberd` and find the appropriate `beam` process and see how long it has been running.

Comment: You are right .. simply calling /etc/init.d/ejabberd restart doesn't seem to restart it. Thanks!